# best deployment approach for VSeWSS 1.2

Tags: sharepoint, wss

Can anyone suggest the best deployment approach for VSeWSS 1.2 based development?

I have been working with this for more than 6 months now.. has anyone tried using WSPBuilder for this purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I Personally prefer using stsdev (http://www.codeplex.com/stsdev). I've used both WSPbuilder and STSDEV. Stsdev offers some development project templates that you create using an stsdev gui, not like the standard project templates you create using new > project.

The stsdev projects has got a Rootfiles folder, which corresponds to the '12 hive' on the destination server. All the files you put into Rootfiles folder and subfolders, is automatically added to solutionpackage.ddf and manifest.xml, so you dont have to worry about editing these files and compiling them using makecab.

Another great thing that stsdev offers is build targets, like build, deploy, redeploy, Refresh Assembly in GAC, retract and upgrade. So stsdev projects automatically compiles the binaries, builds the .wsp package, and runs the stsadm commands according to the build type. You can customise the behavior of the build targets if you like, by editing the Microsoft.SharePoint.targets located in the DeploymentFiles folder of the project. As long as you are only working on the code, Refresh Assembly in GAC is a very fast build method, and you can see the changes in sharepoint immediately after.

An disadvantage of stsdev is if you use source control, the manifest.xml and SolutionPackage.ddf if not checked out, are read only, and will result in a compile error (i usually check out all the files in DeploymentFiles folder when working on a project). So you have to check out these files before building. Another thing is that it takes **all** the files under the Rootfiles, including the hidden vssver2.scc files if you are using source control. The project still builds and deploys without problems, but the files are in the wsp package, and copied to the '12 hive' on the destination server.

I think that compared to WSPbuilder, stsdev lets you customize just about anything of the development project, which i haven't been able to do in WSPbuilder.

Comment: Great.. Thanks Filip.. Do you know any product that will provide a compilations of webparts and etc as once solution... (i want to create a standard solution to give QA team)

Answer (score 3):

You should do yourself a favor and look at VSeWSS **1.3**.  See Kirk Evans' blog for a good video overview: http://blogs.msdn.com/kaevans/archive/2009/03/13/sharepoint-developer-series-part-1-introducing-vsewss-1-3.aspx.

Major downside could be that it requires Visual Studio 2008.

I have been a STSDEV advocate, but am now leaning towards VSeWSS 1.3.  My suspicion is that other WSPBuilder and STSDEV users will feel the same over time, but I haven't finished my evaluation of it yet.

Comment: Looking forward to the final release.. i believe its June yeah??

Answer (score 2):

We have always used WSPBuilder. This is best if you are looking to create wsp's.

It also provides a VS Add-in. You can build, deploy, upgrade etc. right from VS. Provides VS templates like Blank features, Web Part Feature, Feature with Receiver, Workflow feature, Event Handler, Item Template etc...

We manage 20+ projects with WSPBuilder

Comment: Thanks Ganesha.. We have done a lot of work as well.. Do you know how to create one main deployment package that will deploy all the components in one go? (im trying to avoid creating a build script to do that)

Answer (score 2):

As Kirk Liemohn points out, you really should upgrade to VSeWSS 1.3. We took lots of customer feedback and there's lots of new features for developers in this version.

It includes quick deploy commands for deploying just the new binary or just the files into the SharePoint 12 folder structure. It also runs on x64 OS with Visual Studio 2008. It has command line support.

Available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=FB9D4B85-DA2A-432E-91FB-D505199C49F6&displaylang=en)

Comment: Paul and his team have done a lot of work to improve it. I'm still looking for better support of large projects and bin deployment, but it's coming along.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer WSPBuilder as well. I don't have any problem with not being able to configure WSPBuilder the way I want it. In the latest version you can override its settings for each project or developer individually should you want to.

There is also a great add-on to WSPBuilder called SPVisualDev (codeplex.com/spvisualdev). Among other features it provides templates for adding ASCX files and it automatically pushes down files you have put in your project 12-hive folder from VS into the real 12-hive folder.. A huge time saver for me.

Answer (score 0):

One downside to VSeWSS 1.2 was the lack of deploy to bin support. 1.3 adds that, but I haven't gotten it to work with referenced assemblies.
I've switched to [STSDev 2008](http://stsdev2008.codeplex.com/), a spinoff of the original STSDev with bug fixes. I've been working with the main contributors to add documentation to the project on CodePlex, but it's had 1900 downloads in little over a year.

Answer (score 0):

I have used VSeWSS 1.2 and 1.3 and it does make deployment pretty easy. The question I had was, what do you guys usually do if you wanted to distribute the Web Parts to a customer administered SharePoint server.
Do you just take the Release folder and tell them to run the setup.bat script? Do you package it differently? Do you create custom installers?

Comment: VSeWSS 1.2 creates you a WSP and a .bat file. make sure to copy both of them into the same location and run the setup.bat file. you can get the help by typing: setup.bat -help

Answer (score 0):

VSeWSS 1.3 CTP is out now, and *does* have command-line support. That being said, the extensions are IMHO--and based on currently using them for a very large, very complex project--a pain in the rectum for the following reasons:

1. Every time you open a solution of extensions-enabled projects, you will have to sit and wait while the VSeWSS wheedles through each and every project, checking structure and trying to repackage each solution. The wait seems to grow exponentially with every extensions-enabled project you add to the solution. Given all of the waiting already included in doing SharePoint development inside a VM, the wait can be excruciating.
2. While VSeWSS is making its way through the projects, no indication is given of any work going on; VS simply becomes unresponsive.
3. Every time you *close* your VS solution with extensions-enabled projects, VSeWSS does the whole operation over again. Given that, by this time on my current project I'm usually 10 or so hours in the seat, and the last thing I want to do is wait longer to go home, this process is worse that excruciating (if that's even possible.) Most of the devs on our team just go to Task Manager and kill the *devenv.exe*. process rather than waiting.
4. We've had a very bad time of it trying to use the current (CTP) version of the extensions to do an integrated build. We've been having a number of problems using VSeWSS from the command line to do build and packaging of all of our projects.

In brief, use STSDEV. Setting up the folders is kind of a pain, but once you have everything scripted out, you're pretty much set.